# How to replace multiple words in textarea using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code I'm using but this replace only the single word, how can I replace multiple words.
**Input:** Good Morning, this is jack here.
**Output:** Good Evening, this is stack here.

```js
function deleteText() {
  var my = document.getElementById('mytextarea');
  var myvalue = my.value;
  my.value = myvalue.replace("Morning", "Evening");
}
```

```html
<textarea style="text-transform: uppercase; white-space: normal" cols="50" rows="3" id="mytextarea">Good Morning, this is jack here.
</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Delete" onClick="deleteText()">
```

Comment: would you like to replace the whole content? because you can do that by just assigning a new value

Comment: no, only the selective words.

Comment: Why not make another statement like my.value = myvalue.replace("Morning", "Evening"); but with the new content? the first input is what will be replaced and the second is what it will be replaced by. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: You are actually assigning a new value with `my.value = ...` but the answer is just to do all the mutations to the string you want before reassigning it to the input.value

Comment: [codepen](https://codepen.io/kumarmasterpraveen/pen/YzVKOdo), May be this is what you are looking for...

Comment: function deleteText() {
    var my = document.getElementById('mytextarea');
    var myvalue = my.value;

    myvalue = myvalue.replace("Morning", "Evening");
    my.value = myvalue;
  };
This code works, but there might be better solutions out there... :)